# Resolving photos:// URI in react native

Tags: react-native

I have used [react-native-photos-framework](https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework) to retrieve a video URI and upload that video. Problem is it's in the format of

**photos://57CDD486-7F71-43EB-970D-B5CA70C7A61E**

not in the format of

**assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=57CDD486-7F71-43EB-970D-B5CA70C7A61E&ext=MP4**

Thus it gives and error "'-[NSNull hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" and crashes.

How to resolve this URI type?

Comment: Can you not just parse out the id and put it into the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can resolve a URI type that is proprietary to that specific package (which doesn't seem to include a resolver and hasn't been updated in a while).

You can use RCTCamerRoll (part of React Native, but needs to be separately linked) to retrieve a URI from an Album.  It returns the assets-library format for URIs.